# Cell highlight shows default image instead of actual image

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've an avatar image in cells in a table. When I touch a cell (highlight) it shows default avatar image instead of the actual image. I'm not sure what is causing this and how to fix. Any help?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell else {
        fatalError("Can't find cell")
    }
       
    //...
        
    cell.selectionStyle = .default
    self.configCell(cell: cell, indexPath: indexPath)

    //...
    
}

func configCell(cell: TableViewCell, indexPath: IndexPath) {
   
    //...

    // Avatar
    if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
        cell.avatarImageView.image = .defaultImage
        cell.tag = indexPath.row
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if cell.tag == indexPath.row {
                    cell.avatarImageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
        
    } 
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an issue *only* with proper image displaying, I'd suggest working with `highlightedImage` property of `UIImageView`.

`UITableViewCell` has `.highlighted`  property (when the cell is pressed down). Thus, if the cell contains `UIImageView` inside, then when you select/highlight the cell, the `UIImageView` will use the `.highlightedImage` instead of just `.image`.

So just as a backup and fix to the problem, you could *additionally* provide/tell `UIImageView` **to display an avatar** even when it is highlighted.

Comment: Thanks for providing detailed explanation. Setting highlightedImage work.